# Jenkins Workflow - how to execute something ONLY on errors?

Tags: jenkins

**Situation:**

`Jenkins Workflow` offers the possibility to use a "`catchError`" section. However, while normally in code you only do the catch when there is an error, in the `Workflow`, it does it whether there is an error or not.

**Problem:**

I have many code section, and at the end of each, I'd need to do send a email only if there was an error in the current section, and I can't find any tool to do it.

Comment: Where did you get the information about `catchError?` The [tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) of the [Workflow Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) doesn't mention such.

Comment: By trying, it execute this code no matter if an error occurred or not.

Comment: Do you mean _Workflow_ → _Definition_ → [✔] _Snippet Generator_ → _Steps_ → _Sample Step_ → _Catch error and set build result_?

Comment: checked (sorry server was down) and yes it is!!